# How to create C# program to change AD password remotely?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, active-directory

Currently, I have a sharepoint site which is accessed via windows authentication. This site will be accessed through the internet by users. How do I create a C# program that can be hosted online so that users can change their AD password (which is used to log into sharepoint) when accessing through the internet?

If hosting a c# program isn't the smartest idea, what other solutions do I have to change AD password remotely? (Without logging into the computer via windows auth)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a ASP.NET MVC Application and connect to AD with the Directory library: http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

Maybe integrate that as a Web-Part into SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

The company you work for I would imagine would have some other form of application that you access externally with a password reset process. Possibly E-Mail via the web browser etc. Advise that people use another application that already exists to update their password, This way you know your not breaching any company security policies that are currently in place.

Cheers

Truez